# unalble to read clear data from pdf file as other language is not english

Tags: java, pdf, unicode

I am trying to copy some data from pdf to txt file here is the code

```
public void readPDFFile() throws IOException {

        InputStreamReader reader;
        OutputStreamWriter writer;
        FileInputStream inputstream;
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
        String str;
        File rfile = new File(
                "C://Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/EGDownloads/source.pdf");
        File wFile = new File("C://Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/Folder/destination.txt");
        try {
            inputstream = new FileInputStream(rfile);
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(wFile);
            reader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream, "UTF-8");
            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                writer.write(str);
            }
        } catch (IOException es) {
            System.out.println(es.getMessage());
            es.printStackTrace(System.out);
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            if (bufferedWriter != null)
                bufferedWriter.close();
        }

    }
```

Expected output is supposed in other language but all I am getting is some random boxes as tried both `UTF-16` and `UTF-8` unicodes 
I tried **pdfBox** but is still not working as all I'm getting is **only original language accent and in english language**

**Note :**

1  I'm not trying to print data on console but copying from `pdf` to `txt` file

2  Other file contains **non english** words,

can anyone help me to solve that??

Or any link that might help

Thanks.

Comment: That is probably because PDFs are not what you see is what you get. A PDF is encoded and not readable normally.  [Portable Document Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format)

Comment: Then ,is there any way to solve that?? Because **English** is easily readable

Comment: @Underbalanced I can read any document in **English** but it is causing problem when I try to read document in language other then english

Comment: Have you checked the encoding? It appears more then UTF-8 can be used in the PDF. [Document management — Portable document format — Part 1: PDF 1.7](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)

Comment: Please open a PDF with NOTEPAD++ to understand that PDF isn't a "language", it is a binary format. To get useful text, google for: pdf extract text java.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF format is a binary format. You must have a really special PDF as all that I know of are compressed in some way. Use a proper library to read it, be it pdfbox or itext or other. Be aware that in some PDFs it's impossible to extract text, you can check it with Acrobat, if Acrobat can't do it nobody can.